# elm-package.json constraints of 'repo_name/package_name' are probably letting too much stuff through

Tags: elm

I get this error trying to use a github repository as a dependency using elm-install

```
Problem in dependency repo_name/package_name 1.0.0

The elm-package.json constraints of 'repo_name/package_name' are probably
letting too much stuff through.
```

What does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer courtesy of @ilias at Elm Slack channel)

It means that Elm couldn't compile the sources for that package in the context of your package.

Imagine for a minute I'm making a package `my-fancy-package`, and I have a dependency on a package `foo/bar`. So in `my-fancy-package/elm-package.json`, I could have a dependency like `"foo/bar": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"`. Now, perhaps the most recent version of `foo/bar` while I'm developing `my-fancy-package` is `1.5.0`. And in version `1.5.0`, a new function was added that does exactly what I need in `my-fancy-package`, so I start using that function. The core issue is that there currently is no automated way to test that a package actually works with *all the allowed versions of its dependencies*. So now `my-fancy-package` says it depends on `foo/bar` at any version between `1.0.0` and `2.0.0`, while in reality, it really needs to be at least `1.5.0` because I'm using a function from that package.

Now, imagine you're developing an application, and you're using `foo/bar` at version `1.2.3`. According to the semver ranges of `my-fancy-package`, that means you should be able to use it, but if you were to actually try it, you'd receive this error: `my-fancy-package` is stating it is compatible with `foo/bar@1.2.3` while it really needs `1.5.0`.

The reason the error message doesn't simply say "it failed to compile" is because all the published packages are compiled before publishing. The most common reason for a package failing to compile in some context is that its dependencies aren't "accurate": they're letting too much stuff through.

In case of `elm-install` and packages from github, it's harder to say - it could actually be broken package.

Another common cause for this error is a rather silly one - conflicting definitions of infix operators. The associativity and precedence of infix ops can only be defined "globally", so if there are 2 packages that define the same infix operator, that could become a problem

Comment: Notably, in case of elm-install, to get more detailed error info, just put the library in a directory and add the path to the library's `src/` subdir into `"source-directories"` section in `elm-package.json` of the including project (see also: https://discourse.elm-lang.org/t/how-do-i-fork-and-edit-a-third-party-package/1241/2)